# How to solve this inheritance difficulty?

Tags: .net, inheritance

I use class `A` from third-party library. Class has method `M`:

```
public class A
{
    public int M(int x)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I've written my class `B` with method `M`:

```
public class B : A
{
    public void M(params int[] xs)
    {

    }
}
```

And then in class `C` I want to call method `M` of parent class `A`

```
public class C : B
{
    public void M2()
    {
        int result = M(1);
    }
}
```

But compiler marks this line as error. It tries to use method `M` of class `B`, that returns `void`.
How can I solve this collision without rewriting class `B`?

Comment: If you don't want to rewrite B, you can call the method with an array consisting of one integer. Then it will always resolve to the method in B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that `((A)this).M(1)` would help you. Note that if those methods are virtual/overridden somewhere - things could change.

Thus said, I think that hiding method in such a way is a bad idea that communicating either poor design choices or some hackery. At least I can't think out a way when I really need this.

Comment: Indeed. Better to rename B.M to differentiate it from A.M.